# fiddler2 unable to generate certificate

Tags: https, fiddler, makecert

I'm using Fiddler2 (or trying) to capture SSL traffic for a windows desktop gadget hitting an https web service.  It used to work, and then it stopped a couple days ago, always with this error:

```
--------------------------- 
Unable to Generate Certificate 
--------------------------- 
Creation of the interception certificate failed. 
makecert.exe returned -1. 
Results from C:\Program Files\Fiddler2\MakeCert.exe -ss my -n 
"CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by 
http://www.fiddler2.com" -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -r -cy authority -a 
sha1 
Error: Can't create the key of the subject ('JoeSoft') 
Failed 
-------------------------------------------
```

(I swiped the error from the google group for fiddler, although I just posted my own and it should be visible soon).

Has anyone else had this problem and solved it?  Is Fiddler just broken?

Comment: MakeCert clearly isn't working for you, "Fiddler" itself is working fine. Your next step is to collect a process-monitor log and check where you're seeing errors in accessing either the registry or files on disk.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### In Win7

- So go here: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\`
- Select *all* the files (named with UUIDS).
- Move those files to your Desktop or other folder outside `AppData` dir.
- Launch **Fiddler**, go to `Tools` | `Fiddler Options` | `Enable HTTPS decryption`
- See that it works this time (hopefully).
- Move the files back from their temp location (i.e., `Desktop`),
  to their original one:  `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\`
- When one of the files asks whether you want to replace the existing one, `skip` it.

Comment: This is probably the best, simplest answer.

Answer (score 31):

I and others have had this problem.  It is a key directory that already exists in the key store with the same name as the key directory  that Fiddler is trying to create (probably from a previous version of Fiddler).

The key directory on my machine is located in:

```
C:\Users\\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\\[folder-with-big-name]\
```

Note that the conflict was actually the key folder name.  I just renamed the folder and then the key generation worked fine.

See this link for more information: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/httpfiddler/B-Mu6AxgiIc/LY69rWUBshMJ

Comment: +1 But for me renaming didn't worked instead I had to move it [and I then merged the folders back], (but maybe the reason was because I renamed it by appending to it, as of now I am unable to test it as it is already working)

Comment: @yohal, I also tried adding a prefix to the folder name which did not work. Once I removed the folder from the directory it did.

Comment: As stated by dmytroUa below, I also had to uninstall and reinstall Fiddler, actually upgrading to Fiddler4 and it started working after also moving the keystores out, creating the certificate and copying the rest of the keystores back in.

Comment: DO NOT DELETE THE FOLDER! It contains private keys not used by fiddler.

Comment: Not deleting the folder is not a solution but, assuming deleting actually creates more problems, we can remove the folder and put it back again merging with the new folder. That's what I did and it seems fine.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue on my Windows 8 box. Manually removing the key files per @Nicholas-Cloud didn't help me. So I kept trying different things and finally was able to sort this out.

To solve the certificate problem I did the following:

1. In Tools->Options->HTTPS tab unchecked the "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" option. This enabled the "Remove Interception Certificates" button at the bottom of the dialog
2. Clicked the "Remove Interception Certificates" button
3. Said "Yes" to all pop-up messages
4. Enabled the "Decrypt..." option back.
5. The series of pop-up messages will follow as described in [Fiddler Windows 8 Configuration Steps](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureFiddlerForWin8#place-fiddler-root-certificate-in-the-machine%27s-trusted-root-store)

Note: if the above steps don't help you, try re-installing Fiddler and repeating the steps. I did re-installed it first, before getting to HTTP options.

Comment: This worked for me and makes perfect sense since my `AppData` was restored from backup which already contained Fiddler certificates - this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This worked for windows 7 whereas the above two higher upvoted methods did not.

Comment: Thanks! The reinstall part did it for me. You saved my hairs.

Answer (score 12):

fiddler hardcoded command is out of date.

everyone stop deleting folder.

just install the fliddler plugin that claims to generates a "better cert that works with android". its on the official fiddler plugin list.

that plugin will fix it for you.

Comment: This is the most recent and fastest solution, and in my case, the only one that worked.

Comment: This is also the only approach that worked for me on one of my machines

Comment: The extension in question is "CertMaker for iOS and Android".

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. Replacing folder didnt work

Answer (score 8):

If Fiddler certificate generation fails, the proper fix is to hand-pick the existing Fiddler2 private key and delete that. The above PowerShell code to completely destroy user's private key store is very bad idea. It will make every personal certificate useless.

Confirm the problem by running the same command Fiddler2 would run:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2"
makecert.exe -r -ss my -n "CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com" -sky signature -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -h 1 -cy authority -a sha1 -m 120 -b 09/05/2012
```

If the certificate generation fails, existing private key needs to be deleted. See http://poshcode.org/3637 for tool to find private key for a certificate.

Run it:

```
Get-PrivateKeyPath CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot
```

It will return something like `c:\Users\JoeUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\7b90a71bfc56f2582e916a51aed6df9a_f6d54f4e-ff40-450e-9d77-7cfc383b357`
Delete that file and attempt generating the certificate again. It should succeed. Do **NOT** destroy your entire private key store.

Comment: Running `makecert.exe ...` was successful. However at first I renamed/moved folder with no success. (later I restored it)

Answer (score 7):

The simple fix for me was to install the [Fiddler CertMaker](http://fiddler2.com/r/?fiddlercertmaker)

Answer (score 2):

Nicholas' answer is correct. In order to help others find this page too:

This may be helpful if you get the message "Unable to export Fiddler's Root Certificate" when you click the "Export Fiddler Root Certificate to Desktop" button in Fiddler, or call Fiddler.CertMaker.createRootCert() from code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.
This was certainly due to the presence of earlier versions of Fiddler and some incompatibility between them.

The above folder is used only by Fiddler where it stores the certificates that it creates (or at least for personal certificates on your box and Fiddler is certainly the only one using it). You may want to check if you have other personal certificates than Fiddler ones. In IE this is using Tools / internet options / content / certificates / personal.

Totally empty the folder and don't be afraid of the message about removing system files.
Then in Fiddler, select again the options to capture then decrypt the HTTPS traffic.
If required, re export the Fiddler root certificate on the desktop then re import it in IE and FF.
Restart your browsers if required and enjoy.

I suppose instead of removing all that removing only in IE the private certificate issued to DO_NOT_TRUST_FIddlerRoot does the same but I have not tested this.

Remember to turn off the decrypt option as soon as you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Nicholas Cloud's reply, here's a little script that helps you rename that folder:

```
# Find my SID 
$user = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount([Environment]::UserName) $mySID = ($user.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])).Value

# Rename keys folder with a timestamp
$timeStamp = Get-Date -format "ddMMyyhhmmss"
$folder = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath "appData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\$mySID"
Rename-Item -Force $folder "$folder.$timeStamp"
```

Adding a comment to the Nicholas's reply did allow me to format the code so I ended up creating a separate reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the conflicting file by looking for "JoeSoft" in the content of the files from the C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\ path.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error and was only able to solve it by:

1. Updating [fiddlerCore](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore)
2. As @DemytroUa said 'In Tools->Options->HTTPS tab unchecked the "Capture HTTPS CONNECTSs" option. And clicking "Remove Interception Certificates" button at the bottom of the dialog'
3. Opening the cert manager (enter certmgr.msc in the run dialog - windows + r)
4. Navigate into Personal -> Certificates
5. Deleting All "DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot" certificates
6. On Fiddler check "Decrypt HTTPS traffic in Tools->Fiddler Options->HTTPS tab

It is possible that you only have to update fiddlerCore (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331058/duplicate-fiddler-cer-being-inserted-into-certificate-store) SO question for more details), but I listed everything I did to be totally safe.

Answer (score 0):

cd to the installation folder "d:\Program Files\Fiddler"
run the following command

```
makecert.exe -r -ss my -n "CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com" -sky signature -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -h 1 -cy authority -a sha1 -m 120 -b 09/05/2012
```

A certificate will be created and the problem will be solved