# Not able to open HTTPS site (eg: google,facebook) on Startup of Fiddler (FiddlerCore) in C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, fiddler, fiddlercore

I know this question has been asked earlier but no proper answer has been given.
I downloaded the Windows application with code from http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jul/29/Using-FiddlerCore-to-capture-HTTP-Requests-with-NET which is a simple demo of how fiddler works using 'FiddlerCore' library in C#.I had been through the Heading - 'FiddlerCore Certificates don’t stick by Default' in the same link provided above.
This App also has the feature to 'Install Certificate' specifically for https sites.I installed the certificate through the App,selected 'Firefox' process from the list of drop down provided in the App.Opened the http site,all good.Opened the https site,now the real problem starts here - the site tries loading..... but after some time BANG[image]

Comment: I got the answer  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519418/fiddler2-unable-to-generate-certificate)